# How to call class method in different javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This class is included in an external file names `graph.js`.  I'm trying to access the method `drawchart` from its `class graphElement`. The file is included in the html script src. I can even call the `function fetchYearly()` without a problem but that `class method keeps throwing error`. I'm using the library `chart.js`.

Here is my code :

```js
class graphElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#tmpGraph').innerHTML;
    let canvas1 = document.getElementById('graph').shadowRoot.querySelector('#myChart'); let transType = ['Debit', 'Credit'];
    fetchYearlyData('CREDIT');
    fetchYearlyData('DEBIT');
    this.drawChart(transType);

  }
  drawChart(transType) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').shadowRoot.querySelector('#myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: transType[0],
          borderColor: "#f48480",
          pointBorderColor: "#f48480",
          pointBackgroundColor: "#f48480",
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#f48480",
          pointHoverBorderColor: "#f48480",
          pointBorderWidth: 10,
          pointHoverRadius: 10,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
          pointRadius: 3,
          fill: false,
          borderWidth: 4,
          data: dataDB
        },
        {
          label: transType[1],
          borderColor: "#80b6f4",
          pointBorderColor: "#80b6f4",
          pointBackgroundColor: "#80b6f4",
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#80b6f4",
          pointHoverBorderColor: "#80b6f4",
          pointBorderWidth: 10,
          pointHoverRadius: 10,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
          pointRadius: 3,
          fill: false,
          borderWidth: 4,
          data: dataCRD
        }],
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          position: "top"
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
              fontStyle: "bold",
              beginAtZero: true,
              maxTicksLimit: 5,
              padding: 20
            },
            gridLines: {
              drawTicks: false,
              display: false
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              zeroLineColor: "transparent"
            },
            ticks: {
              padding: 20,
              fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
              fontStyle: "bold"
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }
}


function fetchYearlyData(transType) {
  //does some important stuff :)
}
```

I want to call the function `drawchart()` in another file on click. It is included in the script source of html file but throws :
`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: drawChart is not defined error` when called, however the function `fetchYearly()` works completely fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchYearly` is a function. `drawChart` is not: it is an instance method of the class `graphElement`. You need to instantiate a `graphElement` and invoke `drawChart` on it. It will likely look something like

```
let graph = new graphElement();
graph.drawChart();
```

Comment: Ive tried it but it throws **Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: graph is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>** on line `this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#tmpGraph').innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0):

This `graphElement` class is web component, so if your chart element is already visible on screen, you need to find it in DOM tree, but you need to show us more code.